# sending a filled out pdf via php

Tags: php, pdf

I don't have much experience with webdev, so I'm completely open to being completely redirected.

I have a webpage that contains an fillable pdf (a pdf where the user can type in answers) and a button. I want the user to fill out the pdf and then be able to email me the filled out pdf by clicking the button. I already have the pdf visible on the webpage using an iframe, and I was planning on emailing the file using PHP, but I don't know how to get the filled out pdf. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The one that i know of as being best is the [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). I use it quiet often, its easy and direct to get stuff up and going. Tons of example pages as well..

I also use [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) as well.